# Hide a spark property from displaying in the spark web UI without implementing a security filter

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, datastax

The application web UI at http://:4040 lists Spark properties in the “Environment” tab.  All values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line will appear.  **However, for security reasons, I do not want my Cassandra password to display in the web UI.**  Is there some sort of switch to ensure that certain spark properties are not displayed??

Please note, I see some solutions that suggest implementing a security filter and using spark.ui.filters setting to refer to the class.  I am hoping to avoid this complexity.

Comment: what is the key name for your casaandra password?

Comment: @VladoDemcak "spark.cassandra.auth.password"

Comment: looks like your solution comes with spark 2.0.1

Comment: we are currently using 1.6.1.. But that it very good info, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no common solution how to hide your custom property from spark WebUI for previous releases.

I assume you are using spark 2.0 or below (i have not seen feature described below in 2.0) because 2.0.1 supports passwords preprocessing to "*****".

***Check issue SPARK-16796 [Visible passwords on Spark environment page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-16796)***

When we take a look into *apache spark source code* and do some investigation we can see some **processing** how to "hide" property in spark web ui.

[SparkUI](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/SparkUI.scala)
by default the Environment page is attached within initialization `attachTab(new EnvironmentTab(this))` [line 71]

[EnvironmentPage](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/env/EnvironmentPage.scala) renders properties to `EnvironmentPage` as tab in web gui as:

```
def render(request: HttpServletRequest): Seq[Node] = {
    val runtimeInformationTable = UIUtils.listingTable(
      propertyHeader, jvmRow, listener.jvmInformation, fixedWidth = true)
    val sparkPropertiesTable = UIUtils.listingTable(
      propertyHeader, propertyRow, listener.sparkProperties.map(removePass), fixedWidth = true)
    val systemPropertiesTable = UIUtils.listingTable(
      propertyHeader, propertyRow, listener.systemProperties, fixedWidth = true)
    val classpathEntriesTable = UIUtils.listingTable(
      classPathHeaders, classPathRow, listener.classpathEntries, fixedWidth = true)
    val content =
      <span>
        <h4>Runtime Information</h4> {runtimeInformationTable}
        <h4>Spark Properties</h4> {sparkPropertiesTable}
        <h4>System Properties</h4> {systemPropertiesTable}
        <h4>Classpath Entries</h4> {classpathEntriesTable}
      </span>

    UIUtils.headerSparkPage("Environment", content, parent)
  }
```

all properties are rendered  without some kind of hiding preprocessing except `sparkProperties` - with functionality provided in `removePass`.

```
private def removePass(kv: (String, String)): (String, String) = {
    if (kv._1.toLowerCase.contains("password")) (kv._1, "******") else kv
}
```

as we can see every key that contains "password" ***(BTW: in the master branch they also filtering keys with keyword "secret" [check if u are interested in](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/env/EnvironmentPage.scala#L30))***

I cannot tested now but u can try to update spark. so eg. [SparkSubmitArguments.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L104) in `mergeDefaultSparkProperties()` will consider `spark.cassandra.auth.password` as spark and populate as `sparkProperties` (with `removePass` preprocessing).

And at the end of the day in EnvironmentTab in web gui this property should be visible as `****`.